# Mongoid + rails 4 - implementing User & Following: uniquness validation of embedded model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I am using Rails 4.2.1 and Mongoid 4.0.0

I have a `User` model, which embeds the `Following` model. The effect I am trying to reach is:

```
{
    username:  # This is the id
    ...
    followings: [
        {
            _id:
            username:
            datetime:
        }
    ]
}
```

I do not want `followings` to contain entries with the same username. How to achieve this?

I have tried two methods:

1. I put `validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true` in the code for `Following` model. But this validation is global - If I have John and Sam as two users, and John follows Sam, then when Sam wants to follow John, there is an error of duplication.
2. I added an index in the `User` model:

   `index ({ 'followings.username': 1 }, { unique: true, drop_dups: true })`
   The problem with this approach is that, when I create a user John, the followings field for him will have a username `null`, and then if I create a user Sam, an error is thrown because the `null` username is duplicated:

   `E11000 duplicate key error index: myapp_development.users.$followings.username_1  dup key: { : null }`

Really appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out that due to fragmentation issue, this way of modeling `User` and `Following` will cause a **growing size** of the document, and does not make the best use of the 'Rich document' feature, and will impair the performance. From [MongoDB doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-design/):

> In general, embedding provides better performance for read operations,
> as well as the ability to request and retrieve related data in a
> single database operation. Embedded data models make it possible to
> update related data in a single atomic write operation.
>
> However, embedding related data in documents may lead to situations
> where documents grow after creation. With the MMAPv1 storage engine,
> document growth can impact write performance and lead to data
> fragmentation.

So I learned a lesson. Not being considerable enough before. So I will abandon this way of modeling and separate them out into different collections.